Node js, data event not triggering
Can't get this piece of code to print out 'data' into console.
const { stdin: input, stdout: output } = require('node:process');

input.on('data', chunk => console.log('data') );
input.write('Hello!\n');

Any ideas why ??
I expect 'data' to be printed out.

When I run your code, every time I press a key in the node console window, the program prints 'data' on the console. However your .write() call, should be on output, not on input.
